# Getting a specific document from a nested Firstore subcollection to a streambuilder

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

So, I'm trying to display a document field but it's not working if I'm entering from a previous page. How do I display this type of subcollection from a material page route, my flutter app keeps on crashing.

```
new StreamBuilder(
                    stream: Firestore.instance
                        .collection("Users")
                        .document(uid) //from firestore getuserID
                        .collection("orders")
                        .document(widget.doc) //from materialpageroute fetched data
                        .snapshots(),
```

or is this not yet supported?

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Its giving error because your data coming from Firestore is A DocumentSnapshot type data . But in your StreamBuilder , You must have Specified QuerySnapshot type data

Comment: It's actually a DocumentSnapshot, I just displayed the widget.doc instead of grabbing the document from the Streambuilder.. thank you